# How do I update a single file in a zip archive

Tags: bash, zip

How do I update a single file in a zip archive? (Surprisingly, I couldn't find the info in the existing threads).

Let's say I have a some.zip archive and I want to replace a path/in/zip/file1.txt inside the archive with /path/on/my/linux/file1.txt on my system.

A command like the following doesn't work for me:
zip -f some.zip path/in/zip/file1.txt /path/on/my/linux/file1.txt

Answer (score 4):

If you need to replace and rename, you will probable have to issue several commands. So assuming you want to replace `path/in/zip/b` in the archive by `path/on/linux/b` (keeping the original name in the archive):

```
# Delete original
zip -d f.zip path/in/zip/b
# Add new
zip f.zip path/on/linux/b
# Rename
printf "@ path/on/linux/b\n@=path/in/zip/b" | zipnote -w f.zip
```

An alternate syntax for the "rename" part, somehow more readable (to me at least):

```
zipnote -w f.zip << EOF
@ path/on/linux/b
@=path/in/zip/b
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks you made my day! The last command was complaining about some incorrect format till I modified it to printf "@ path/on/linux\n@=path/in/zip\n" | zipnote -w f.zip

Comment: Just curious, zip command itself doesn't support renaming one path to another?

Comment: @Andrei Glad if it helps. Feel free to vote up and/or accept the answer ;) As about your comments: (Comment1) Curious. Probably some discrepancies between the various version of the tool? I use ZipNote 3.0 (July 5th 2008) on Debian Wheezy. (comment2) No! This is ashame, but it doesn't ... a least on my Debian box (Zip 3.0 July 5th 2008).

Comment: @Andrei Regarding your first comment, I add an alternate syntax -- that works here. Feel free to try it if you like (as you noticed `zipnote` is quite strict about the syntax; you cannot have any space before the `@`...)

Answer (score 3):

You basically have *3* options to *update* an archive: *add*, *update* and *freshen*

> ```
>    add
>           Update existing entries and add new files.  If the archive  does
>           not exist create it.  This is the default mode.
>
>    update (-u)
>           Update  existing entries if newer on the file system and add new
>           files.  If the archive does not exist issue warning then  create
>           a new archive.
>
>    freshen (-f)
>           Update  existing entries of an archive if newer on the file sys‐
>           tem.  Does not add new files to the archive.
> ```

The later two *might* or *might not* update the archive depending on the relative timestamp of the file and the archive. My guess is for some reason you have an issue regarding that matters. Maybe a wrong timestamp in the archive? Or some discrepancies between file systems?

Anyway, to update a ZIP archive *regardless of file timestamp*, you just have to use the `zip` command without a flag. Here is an example session demonstrating that:

1) Create the archive:

```
sylvain@bulbizarre:/tmp/u$ echo a | tee f1 | tee f2 > f3
sylvain@bulbizarre:/tmp/u$ zip f.zip f1 f2 f3
  adding: f1 (stored 0%)
  adding: f2 (stored 0%)
  adding: f3 (stored 0%)
```

2) Alter a file and *update* the archive

```
sylvain@bulbizarre:/tmp/u$ echo b > f2
sylvain@bulbizarre:/tmp/u$ zip f.zip f2
updating: f2 (stored 0%)
```

3) Extract and check the content of the archive

```
sylvain@bulbizarre:/tmp/u$ unzip f.zip
Archive:  f.zip
replace f1? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
 extracting: f1                      
 extracting: f2                      
 extracting: f3                      
sylvain@bulbizarre:/tmp/u$ cat f?
a
b
a
```

Comment: What would be the command to update a file with a path, not just zip f.zip f2, what is f2 has a long path in f.zip?

Comment: @Andrei As this is somewhat a different question as what I have understood first, I post below a different answer. Hope this help!